# What to do after TcpListener times out?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcplistener

It seems really strange that I can't seem to find an answer to this question.  When trying to use a TcpListener in a C# windows forms application, I can set timeouts on a TcpListener's Server object, but what do I do when a timeout occurs?  How do I recognize that it happened?  In low-level socket programming in Python, I can specify a timeout event handler, but I don't see a way to do that in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SendTimeout` value is *only* used when using the synchronous `Send`. When the timeout is hit, `Send` will throw a `SocketException` - that's how you know the `Send` failed.

In practice, you shouldn't really do anything with the underlying winsocket object - all you should need in almost all cases are the methods and properties exposed by `TcpListener` and `TcpClient` themselves.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to answer.